# Why NestedScrollView stop scrolling when CollapsingToolbarLayout is completely collapse?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, nestedscrollview

I am using `collapsingToolbarlayout` with `nestedscrollview` and it works fine, until the `collapsingToolbarlayout` is completely collapse and `actionbar` is showing. Here the `nestedscrollview` stop scrolling and some items still hidden.

here is my xml file

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/topLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/BigThumbnailImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/bg_health_news"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            >

            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                layout="@layout/place_item_details_views"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have searched a lot & I don't know why it happens

thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I have find out the problem is I am including a layout that contains a `horizontalscrollview` and when it empty or contains data it causes this issue if someone knows this problem can help me thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason is that your last items are out of the screen, because of shift, so you can try to add:

```
android:paddingBottom="<your toolbar height in collapsed state>"
```

to your NestedScrollView. In my case that helped.