# NestedScrollView wont't scroll to the end when used with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I want to use NestedScrollView with CollapsingToolbarLayout. In NestedScrollView there is really long content. Unfortunately I can't scroll to the end. Some of this long content is cut. What is strange when I turn screen, scrolling works fine and all content is visible.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/u8"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- lots of widgets-->

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT: I noticed that height of cut content is the same as Toolbar height.

Comment: What happens if you set the height of the LinearLayout to `wrap_content`?  Typically, any layout inside a scrolling widget gets `wrap_content` in the direction of the scroll.

Comment: Nothing. Still cannot scroll to the end.

Comment: same problem here. i tried adding  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in places and also  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to manifest. all ideas failed so far.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: hey mate! have you found the solution?

Comment: To be honest I don't remember now.

Comment: I faced same issue, solved by removing marginTop and marginBottom propertys from child layout of NestedScrollView, i use padding instead, hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712401/why-nestedscrollview-stop-scrolling-when-collapsingtoolbarlayout-is-completely-c/33777902#33777902). Adding paddingBottom to NestedScrollView resolved this issue for me:

```
android:paddingBottom="<toolbar height in collapsed state>"
```

Comment: If you use the default height of the toolbar you can use `?attr/actionBarSize`

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing the similar issue where the NestedScrollView wouldn't scroll to the end when the keyboard is open.

Placing the AppBarLayout after the NestedScrollView did the trick for me. Do let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. One of the reasons for this bug was not setting the SupportActionBar

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

(I didn't to do it because I needed toolbar only for the collapsing toolbar to work as expected and I thought it wasn't important to setSupportActionBar)

And the other one was: it was working inside the activity, but in a fragment wasn't working correctly (maybe it was an issue of that specific version of support library that I used)

Answer (score 4):

What causes this for me is "exitUntilCollapsed" line in my CollapsingToolbarLayout:
`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">`

It causes problem when used with "scroll".
I couldn't also use marginBottom because I have an instant translate option which refreshes the TextViews with new content, and when that happens it mysteriously decides to scroll even further more, which ends up in a really bad looking empty space at the bottom.

I solved it using "enterAlwaysCollapsed" instead and moved my toolbar to the very top, outside the collapse. It's not exactly what I want but so far I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Really Thanks , I have spend i week on it. it works for me

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since asking the question. But maybe setting `minHeight` attribute in CollapsingToolbarLayout like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44654007/4656400) might help somebody as well.

Comment: this answer is correct, I can come up with some "developer like explanation" to support this solution, but not 200% sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

Due to Toolbar pinned(with CollapsingToolbar). Nestedscrollview failed to adjust the bottom view with the screen.

If you set toolbar on the setSupportActionBar. NestedScrollView will fit with the screen.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" property and nested scroll view it will work

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/task_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```